# How can I upload a file larger than 10MB on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, limit

I am working on a university project using GitLab and DocBook, and I just finished the final version of the PDF. The problem is that there is a file limit (max. 10MB) and I have no idea how to access the limit settings using the browser version of GitLab.

I would love to change the file size limit for my repos, because as far as I can tell, it is possible to upload large files, you just have to change the limit somewhere and somehow.

Comment: How is this supposed to be a programming question? This better belongs to google

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for self managed only.

```
The Size limit per repository (MB) field in the Account and limit section of a 
GitLab instance’s settings by navigating to either:
Admin Area > Settings > General.
The path /admin/application_settings.
```

This should be the answer, you are looking for.
You have to have rights to to do that, ofc.

Source:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#how-it-works

Comment: The OP is likely asking about GitLab CE, not EE.